# Linux Shell: remove all HTML files in tree while leaving directory structure

Tags: linux, rm

I'm trying to remove all .html files from the directory `generated` and from all subfolders there but it needs to leave all other files and directories alone.

I tried going through folder by folder and running `rm *.html` but this takes a long time as there are 20+ subfolders which also have subfolders. I tried looking the man pages for `rm` but nothing obvious jumped out. I'm sure there's a way to do this in one shot but I don't know how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this may work:

`cd generated`

`find . -type f -iname "*.html" -delete`

Comment: +1 for the delete switch seemingly noone knows about